# Download progress using Amazon s3 sdk for Unity

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, awss3transfermanager

I am using Amazon s3 Unity sdk to download a zip file from s3 server. During download I want to show a download progress bar on the screen. I didn't get any property/method giving download progress while downloading. Can anyone please help me how out how can I get download progress? Is there any indirect method to do this?

Here is my downloading code :

```
 Client.GetObjectAsync(BUCKET, fileName, (responseObj) =>
            {
                string data = null;
                var response = responseObj.Response;

                if (response.ResponseStream != null)
                {
                    using (BinaryReader bReader = new BinaryReader(response.ResponseStream))
                    {
                        byte [] buffer = bReader.ReadBytes((int)response.ResponseStream.Length);
                        File.WriteAllBytes(path, buffer);

                    }
                } else {
                    _isError = true;
                }

            });
```

Comment: No, this is Amazon S3 client in c# Unity

Comment: I want to know this too, hope someone answers this soon.